# iOS Charts Disable Zoom

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

How do you disable zoom for iOS Charts but not completely stop user interaction? For example, still using the highlight tap. This takes care of the zoom, but it disables everything else as well.

```
chartView.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 5):

To disable zoom, but not impact other chart interaction, make these adjustments:

```
chartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
chartView.scaleXEnabled = false
chartView.scaleYEnabled = false
```